# How to set http headers with different content type

Tags: python, html, http, header, http-headers

I have a webpage dynamically created via Python. Its purpose is to provide images, so the first line sets the content type:

```
Content-Type: image/png
```

I would like to set http headers, specifically cache controlling, but I'm not too sure how as the content type is not html, so I'm sure I cant put html style headers into it.

EDIT: The code starts simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import string, sys, math, os
print("Content-Type: image/png\n")
```

Comment: What framework/library are you using?  The answer is completely dependent on that info.  (And trivial to discover once you have it.)

Comment: The page is on an Apache 2.2 server and is created via Python 2.7.1 with no extensions or modules

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet with the relevant imports/calls?

Comment: I added the start of the code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache-Control, Content-Type and the like are HTTP headers, not "html style headers". You can use them regardless of the content-type.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was being silly and dismissing the fact that _Content-Type_ is an http header, I was thinking the headers had to go in the html head. I've fixed the code by just sticking extra headers in the first line separated by semi-colons. Thanks.

Comment: @Arty-fishL You mean semi-colons in the Python code? You don't need to do that. You can have the print statements on separate lines. Your web server doesn't really care how you format your code. It just cares about the format of its output. Primarily, you want "name: value" lines for the HTTP headers, a blank line, and then the body of your content. Again, that's the format of the *output*, not of your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string, sys, math, os
print("Cache-Control: max-age=" + str(86400 * 3650) + ", public")
print("Content-Type: image/png")
print("\n")
```

That sets the resource to expire in ten years.

Comment: Its CGI, not the whole webserver (it runs on heliohost.org servers) and I will put the start of the code in the question