# Django development server and MIME types

Tags: django, mime-types, google-chrome-devtools, django-dev-server

Is there anyway of setting MIME types in the django development server?
Specifically, I would love to remove this message from the warnings in Chrome dev tools.

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/x-png
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as adding

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("image/png", ".png", True)
```

to settings.py

Comment: I had an issue with Django serving javascript ES6 modules as text/plain with the included server and this solved it (with "application/javascript" and ".js").

Comment: Same issue here. But only works if I include the ES module file in the primary project static dir. Any .js file served in an app directory is given a content-type of text/html :-(

Answer (score 4):

The Django development server uses the [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) module to guess the appropriate MIME type for any given file, and under the hood that module uses different configurations depending on your OS.

On Windows in particular it loads content types from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the registry (for instance the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type` for .js files) and it seems this configuration can often be set in ways you wouldn't expect (such as by opening a javascript file in a text editor)- it's not even Python or Django specific, since [Go also uses the registry and is affected the same way](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32350).

Modifying the registry key for the affected file extensions should fix this issue without requiring any Django settings changes (however it is a system-wide configuration change that may not be desirable):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Fixing the question's issue with PNG
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png]
"Content Type"="image/png"

; Fixing a common problem with Javascript files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js]
"Content Type"="text/javascript"
```

On other operating systems MIME mappings are configured in a file that most users will never modify, so this tends not to be a problem. If needed however, `mimetypes.knownfiles` is a list of paths expected to contain MIME type mappings which could be edited as needed.

Comment: @It helped in EDGE browser but doesnt work in Opera for some funny reson . Windows...

Answer (score 0):

**Year 2020 ANSWER:**

if you want any mime content type to auto detect by browser this is the solution.

after many painful failed **static** attempts this is the **dynamic** solution.

```
def fetch(request):
    import mimetypes
    clientRequestUrl=os.getcwd()+'/servlet'+request.path
    try: return HttpResponse(fread(clientRequestUrl), content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(request.path)[0])
    except Exception as e: return HttpResponse(str(e)+'===> Error Thrown <br>')
```

- **here fread() reads file directly** in try except block its just an I/O wrapper
- content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(request.path)[0] does the **MIME** detection magic [0] ie first element is required because it returns a tuple first being the mime type and second being encoding.
- request.path is passed in above line because it guesses **MIME** based on file path. for example text/css for file named stylsheet.css if client(browser) request it.
- clientRequestUrl = exact url the client is trying to request to server.