# Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: | Django Framework

Tags: django, mime

I know in Apache One adds

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !(\.ico\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g|\.css|\.js|\.php|\.eot|\.svg|\.ttf|\.woff|\.otf|^public/.*)$ index.php [nocase,last]
```

but How I do with Django, these rules

Comment: ... Okay, even *I* can't fix *this* one...

Comment: thanks for reply, upvote the question, so others may find it and will solve this

Comment: I had these particular warnings (still have actually). The only thing I found was this: `mimetypes.add_type('application/font-otf', '.otf', True)`, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you are serving static files in Django dev server?

In `settings.py` I think you need:

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/font-woff", ".woff", True)
```

...from info given in these questions on SO:

[Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/x-font-woff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704967/resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-application-x-font-w)
[Django development server and MIME types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303098/django-development-server-and-mime-types)

Comment: great, awesome, nice.As I am using google maps API, My django server is not serving the .woff files but from google server with this error in console `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff"`, so how I can solve this?

Comment: It is only a Warning from Chrome, not an Error. You can safely ignore the warning. In future versions of Chrome this warning will not be shown - see this ticket: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=248712

Comment: interesting to note: it appears the `font/woff` mime type that Chrome is complaining about will in future be the *correct* mime type