# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, mime-types, django-debug-toolbar

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEogao-tUec) video while installing the django debug toolbar as well as the [docs](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html). However, I just cannot get it to work. The mime type error keeps popping up in the console tab of the dev tools.

[image]

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'this is secret'

DEBUG = True

 if DEBUG:
     import mimetypes
     mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)


INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]


ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    '127.0.0.1',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'demo.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'mdeia')


# debug toolbar settings

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
]


def show_toolbar(request):
    return True

DEBUB_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': show_toolbar
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from .views import home, java_script




urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('.*\.js', java_script),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {})



def java_script(request):
    filename = request.path.strip("/")
    data = open(filename, "rb").read()
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have also set the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type` in the registry editor to `text/javascript` as shown below.

[image]

There is an exact same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013643/failed-to-load-module-script-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-ty), there was an ask for further info but none was provided and I do not have the ability to add comments. Hence a brand new question.

Edit: The toolbar shows up in microsoft edge, WTF!!!

Answer (score 0):

### refer below code resolved this issue.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def java_script(request):
    filename = request.path.strip("/")
    data = open(filename, "rb").read()
    # return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/x-javascript")
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    #enter code here
```

Comment: There is no change in the output. I can still see the toolbar in edge, but it is stubbornly absent in chrome. And again that console error is still there in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

**Not An Actual Answer** *but still*

I don't know exactly what random thing changed that got the toolbar to start working out of the blue! But the toolbar is now showing up in the original project I actually wanted it to work in. And it's still working in edge as well.

The above project(*see question*) was a clean slate to test out the django debug toolbar ***itself***. I wanted to see how/if it works in an isolated environment.

The only changes that I remember making are:

- Reconnecting a bluetooth device
- Uncheck show small icons in taskbar
- Auto hide taskbar when in desktop mode

The settings and urls code for the **Original project** is shown *below*:

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = Again, this is secret

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


INTERNAL_IPS = [
    'localhost',
    '127.0.0.1',
]


ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    '127.0.0.1',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'auctions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'commerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'commerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auctions.User'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_R00T = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


# Default django debug toolbar settings


def show_toolbar(request):
    return True


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
]


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': show_toolbar
}
```

Project level urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import debug_toolbar

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auctions.urls")),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

App level urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = "auctions"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create_listing", views.create_listing, name="create_listing"),
    path("listing/<str:listing>", views.listing_detail, name="detail_view")
]
```

Test Project
[image: Test Project]

Original Project
[image: Original Project]

## **Update**

I made a some changes to the original project *(wanted to make changes to the models)*:

- deleted the sqlite .db file
- also deleted the migrations folder

Unfortunately these actions affected the django debug toolbar, as in made it go away. To bring back the toolbar I did `git reset --hard <ref name>` *where ref name is the previous commit where the toolbar was present*. However, this did not work.

Also the the django debug toolbar disappeared from the test project that I had created, even though I did not make any changes to the code or directory structure for that project.