# javascript file loading problem in a web browser, relating to mime types, context Django debug_toolbar concerning Django/debug_toolbar versions >=3.X

Tags: django, debugging, toolbar, django-3.0, django-debug-toolbar

I have noticed, at some point last year, that the debug_toolbar is not present anymore. Now I have found the problem, but do not actually completely understand what is happening and why. [Update: I have found an answer - see the last few paragraphs ]

The initial information is that I tried a lot of different version combinations for Django/delug_toolbar and there were no problems as the version number of both started by 2.

However, the toolbar is not showing itself if a version number starts by 3. The toolbar 2.2 should work with Django version 3 or larger also.

Now I have located the problem to be that toolbar.js is not loaded. There is a message in the developer tool's console:

:8001/static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

So I found the location of the toolbar.js under the static files folder of the debug_toolbar.

The file is loaded in a template base.html (in folder env\Lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\templates\debug_toolbar)

There is a line:

```
<script type="module" src="{% static 'debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js' %}" async></script>
```

But I do not understand why type="module" is preventing the browser to load and use the toolbar.js?

There was a section in the (https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-debug-toolbar/downloads/pdf/stable/) Django Debug Toolbar manual that said in case of the problem with mimetypes the user should edit Windows registry.

"1.6 Troubleshooting
On some platforms, the Django runserver command may use incorrect content types for static assets. To guess content types, Django relies on the mimetypes module from the Python standard library, which itself relies on the underlying platform’s map files. If you find improper content types for certain files, it is most likely that the platform’s map files are incorrect or need to be updated. This can be achieved, for example, by installing or updating the mailcap package on a Red Hat distribution, mime-support on a Debian distribution, or by editing the keys under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the Windows registry"

Could someone please give me an explanation for what is going on here? I tried to find if there was any discussion about this problem with these new Django/Django Debug Tool versions but there was nothing to be found. The other discussion was concerning about the earlier versions.

Do I have a security setting of a browser (etc) that is causing the problem as there is no question about the people that have made the Debug toolbar would have implemented their code/settings not to work at all? I have tried Firefox/Edge/Chrome and the issue is in all of them.

I found a tip from another question.

By adding

if DEBUG:
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

to settings.py causes that the toolbar.js is loaded.

That addition solved the whole problem. There is no need to do anything for the Windows registry.

The discussion can be found here:

[Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013643/failed-to-load-module-script-the-server-responded-with-a-non-javascript-mime-ty)

So my question was in fact a duplicate.